# Safari + position fixed + zoom bug fix with jquery

Tags: jquery, css-position, safari

Could somebody help me calculate a elements top position based on page zoom.
A little explanation: In desktop safari elements with position fixed wont stick to their position in viewport **when the page is zoomed** 
So I thought I'll try to calculate the top value with jQuery based on browser zoom. I'm able to get a zoom level using **$(window).height()** and **window.innerHeight** because when the page is zoomed in then these values are different from each other in Safari(if i remember correctly then in Chrome and FFox they remain the same). Also Im able to get the window scrollTop value, that also changes with page zoom.
But now I'm stuck and don't know how to use these values to calculate the top value for my element. Weak math skills :(

In a perfect world the fixed element would remain always at 10px from the top, no matter the zoom or page scroll.
Heres a quick test HTML ([link to the same file pasted below](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42238336/SafariZoomBug/index.html))

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Safari Zoom Bug Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var winH = $(window).height();//Window height
                var winIh = window.innerHeight;//Window inner height... If you zoom in in Safari then this is smaller then window Height
                var Zoom = winIh / winH; //Calculate the zoom level
                var winSc = $(window).scrollTop();//Get window scroll position

                var oFF = winSc*Zoom;//"Normalize" the scroll top according to Zoom level

                $('#foo').css('top',oFF);//Update the fixed position element height

                });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body style="height:4000px;">
<div id="foo" style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;height:100px;width:100px;background:red;">
Im supposed to have fixed position no matter the zoom level
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. The answer is to set position absolute and just use the window.scrollTop
It looks something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

                var winSc = $(window).scrollTop();//Get window scroll position
$('#foo').css('top',winSc);//Update the fixed position element height

                });
```